# How to dequeue a linked list in c if the element to be returned is not of primitive type?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have this data structure:

```
typedef struct task
{
    void (*function)(void *p);
    void *data; // in my case, this is a struct with two integers
    struct task *next;
}Task;
```

I want to have a dequeue function that returns the first element of type Task:

```
struct task* dequeue()
{    
    if (!head) {
        return NULL;
    }
    
    Task *taskToReturn = head;

    /********************
    * PROBLEM'S HERE
    ********************/        

    head = head->next;

    return taskToReturn;
}
```

Now, the problem is straightforward. I can't assign *head* to *taskToReturn* for the simple reason that I am changing the value pointed by *head* right after. How can I return an element that holds a struct and a function pointer and dequeue it?

Is it at all possible to get the element with a call like that?

```
Task *taskToDo = dequeue();
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's fine that @dbush solved your issue, but for the next time it would be better to upload a small main to reproduce the bug. Also, deleting the faulty line from your question is not a good idea, because now your code doesn't match the original issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing to return the node you want is correct.  The error here is that you're freeing the current head of the list.  Stepping through the code:

```
Task *taskToReturn = head;
```

Here you're saving the current head in `taskToReturn`.

```
head = head->next;
```

Here you're repointing `head` to the second node in the list.  Now `head` no longer points to the same node that `taskToReturn` points to.

```
free(head);
```

By doing this, you've lost you link to the rest of the list.  Get rid of this line and you should be fine.